# (ngx-admin/Nebular) How to integrate Grid system with nebular?

Tags: angular8, nebular, ngx-admin

I want to build Grid structure for Desktop tablet and mobile.
Wrapper class .row and column class .col*** not there in scss.
Do we need to import any css/scss file for dark theme?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ngx-admin template uses the Bootstrap grid system.  The scss files for bootstrap would be in your `node_modules` folder.  You should be able to structure your grid just like you would with Bootstrap

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/